# How can I get an Image from a blob type of MySql database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to show an image in a picturebox from a blob type stored in a database. 
In my program I receive the query data with a reader and load them into an object. Then I use the properties of the object to show the image in a picturebox. With my current code the image appears blank.

The query works well, the problem is when it comes to transforming the blob type of the database to type Image.

```cs
MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(consulta, Conexion.Con);

Conexion.AbrirConexion();  //open connection

MySqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        byte[] num = (byte[])reader[4];
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(num);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        Image image = returnImage;

        usuario.Nombre = reader.GetString(1);
        usuario.Nickname = reader.GetString(2);
        usuario.Contrasenya = reader.GetString(3);
        usuario.Imagen = image;
    }
}
Conexion.CerrarConexion();  //close connection
```

Comment: Whats the issue here. Any Errors?

Comment: There's no Visual Studio error, the picturebox just loads a completely blank image

Comment: Well, my bad. This actually works, I was just choosing the wrong field at the reader

Comment: Side note, memory stream should be in a using block, as it implements IDisposable